# How to compare a value from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

The structure is this:

```
{ID: [name, last name, login, password}

dic={'0002': ['Frank', 'Castle', 'franstle', 'franny.casty'], '0001': ['Juan', 'Botero', 'jbotero', 'snf23jn4'], '0003': ['Logan', 'James', 'jagan', '87654321']}
```

So I ask for someone's login and get the key where it's located, like this:

```
key=''.join([k for k, v in dic.items() if login in v])
```

With this key, I created a list made of the values in dic[key], in order to ask for the password and compare:

```
login=input('Login: ')
lista=[]
key=''.join([k for k, v in dic.items() if login in v])
lista=dic[key]
```

But when login is not in any value from the dic shows this:

```
Login: nada

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
list=dic[key] KeyError: ''
```

What should I do, if the login is not in the dic, I'd like to get 'None'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for

```
if key in dic
```

like this:

```
dic={'0002': ['Frank', 'Castle', 'franstle', 'franny.casty'], '0001': ['Juan', 'Botero', 'jbotero', 'snf23jn4'], '0003': ['Logan', 'James', 'jagan', '87654321']}
login=input('Login: ')
lista=[]
key=''.join([k for k, v in dic.items() if login in v])
if key in dic:
  lista=dic[key]
  print(lista)
else:
  print(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do, if the login is not in the dic, I'd like to get 'None'

For your code, it could be:

```
key = ''.join([k for k, v in dic.items() if login in v]) or None
```

Or better:

```
lista = dic.get(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uset `get` method:

> get(key[, default])
>
> ```
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this
> ```
>
> method never raises a KeyError.

Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html